# Source Link does not work with Blazor web assembly

Tags: debugging, blazor-webassembly, sourcelink

Visual Studio comes with a [Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/sourcelink) feature that basically allows you to debug 3rd party assemblies given that their debug symbols have been published on a source server. This works fine for the server side of things but does not work for web assembly projects with Blazor. Is this simply not supported? I noticed that the browser (Chrome) does not download the pdb files for these 3rd party assemblies. Only for the "top level" assemblies that are part of the solution. I have disabled "Enable just my code" and source link is activated (otherwise it wouldn't even work on the server side). I am using .NET 7.